# Prometheus query for 5% failed uri in last 30 min with the name of last 5% failed uri

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Actually I am new to Prometheus so I need list of 5% failed uri in last 30 minute.

metrics(http_server_requests_seconds_count)
column in metrics(
Time,
**name**,
application,
applicationName,
cluster,
environment,
exception,
hostname,
instance,
job,
method,
namespace,
outcome,
pod_name,
prometheus,
prometheus_replica,
status,
uri)

Comment: This might do:
`
(
  sum by(url) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{status=~"5.."}[30m]))
  /
  sum by(url) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[30m]))
) > 0.05
`

Answer (score 0):

Calculation for all requests.

```
            (sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{status!="200"}[30m])) / sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{}[30m]))) > 0.05
```